# Cinnamon session crashing login from greeter

Tags: dpkg, cinnamon, glib

I wanted to change my desktop environment (DE) to cinnamon because it was way faster on my test computer.

I ran the command:
`apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment`

Rebooted.

Changed the DE to Cinnamon.

Put my password in, and then it kicked me back into the greeter.

When I looked at the logs, I found this error message:

```
Mar  5 13:28:39 lab-linux-01 cinnamon-session[7991]: GLib-GIO-ERROR: t+0.01202s: Settings schema 'org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing' does not contain a key named 'enabled'#012aborting...
Mar  5 13:28:39 lab-linux-01 kernel: [  588.104932] traps: cinnamon-sessio[7991] trap int3 ip:7fc180cd3ad1 sp:7fffb34390a0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.5502.0[7fc180c82000+113000]
```

Googling around for this error message did not yield very much help.

Comment: Exact same issue!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The key were these parts of the message:  `GLib-GIO-ERROR` and `Settings schema 'org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing'`

Where does GLIB store its schemas?

`/user/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

```
$ cd /user/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
$ grep file-sharing *
Binary file gschemas.compiled matches
org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing.gschema.xml:<schema path="/org/gnome/desktop/file-sharing/" id="org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing" gettext-domain="gnome-user-share">
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing.gschema.xml
gnome-user-share: /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing.gschema.xml
```

Aha - gnome-user-share looks like the culprit!

What does gnome-user-share do?

```
$ apt search gnome-user-share
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
gnome-user-share/bionic,now 3.18.3-3 amd64 [installed]
  User level public file sharing via WebDAV
```

I do not need **User level public file sharing via WebDAV**, so I will remove it.

```
$ apt-get purge gnome-user-share
```

I rebooted the computer and was able to login to a nice Cinnamon desktop.

<sub>Time to go make some Cinnamon Toast.  Does anyone have a good recipe for that for that? **;-)**</sub>

Comment: This solved my problem when updating Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, I could log into Gnome but Cinnamon had problems until I removed `gnome-user-share`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Gargravarr if question and answer was useful, please upvote them if you can.  Thanks :)

Comment: already did :) posted the comment so it gets found by Google

Comment: @David deserves some cinnamon rolls ! This solved my problem :)

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Did anybody report this as a bug?