# Unable to log in to Cinnamon session 18.04

Tags: cinnamon, 18.04

I used to use Cinnamon as my desktop environment on 17.10. After I updated to 18.10 I reinstalled Cinnamon using `sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment` but can no longer log in to that specific environment.

After I type in my password there is a pause, the screen goes black, and then returns to the original log in screen.

I am able to start Cinnamon from the terminal when I am already in another session (I use xfce otherwise) using `cinnamon --replace` and everything works as expected.

I have also tried `lightdm` and `gdm3` both with the same result (in fact `gdm3` won't let me boot into xfce, but it will let me boot into gnome). And setting the ownership of my home directory with `chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER`

I am not sure what sort of error log information I should add to this post that would help, but I can add any suggestions from the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing the same problem.

Try out the solution here : [Cinnamon session crashing login from greeter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012087/cinnamon-session-crashing-login-from-greeter)

It worked perfectly for me. Seems `gnome-user-share` was the problem.

Comment: I was just looking at your post as you wrote this

Comment: That wasnt my solution but glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to install Cinnamon meta-package with

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

then log-out and log-in again into *Cinnamon* session.

I'm not sure but sometimes restoring owner of the home-folder solves many issues by

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER
```

Also you can try to set LightDM as default login-screen:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm # select lightdm here
```

then try to log-in.

Comment: This was my original install method, I added some more details to the original post.

Comment: Updated answer with `chown`.

Comment: Didn't seem to have any effect either, added to original post.