# Unable to log in to to Cinnamon without snapd 18.10

Tags: login, lightdm, snap, cinnamon

I have recently re-installed an Ubuntu 18.10 system and installed `cinnamon` with:

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

as well as `lightdm`, and also proceeded to purge `unity` and `gdm3`.

I have a similar issue to [Unable to log in to Cinnamon session 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029743/unable-to-log-in-to-cinnamon-session-18-04).
After I type in my password there is a pause, the screen goes black, and then returns to the original log in screen.

However unlike the linked issue, `gnome-user-share` is not installed. Instead, I found that reinstalling `snapd` after I had previously purged it allowed me to login to Cinnamon. This is an oddity to me since previously I was using an 18.04 system upgraded to 18.10 where `snapd` was uninstalled in 18.04 and Cinnamon functioned just fine.

These are the contents of `.xsession-errors.old`: https://pastebin.com/6uPZZwi, the only error being:

```
(process:1076): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 20:42:00.980: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
```

These are the contents of my custom `lightdm` config in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-autologin.conf` :

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest = false
autologin-user = polly
autologin-user-timeout = 0
user-session = Cinnamon

[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest = false
```

Is there any way to recognize the connection between `snapd` and `cinnamon`?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install --reinstall gsettings-desktop-schemas`
solved it for me. Seems typing out your question makes it easier to actually google it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that somehow the ownership of /home/user/.Xauthority
has been changed.

```
sudo chown user:user ~/.Xauthority
```